# flutter_downloader local network

Tags: flutter, flutter-downloader

I just started using flutter and tried the file download feature using the flutter_downloader plugin (**[link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader)**). When this plugin is used and there is internet access, the feature runs. But when this plugin is used on a local network, this feature doesn't work. The data/files to be downloaded are on the local network.

Has anyone experienced this, and is it really necessary to use the flutter_downloader plugin with internet access? I tried to read the documentation, and there doesn't seem to be any explanation regarding this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6 ? 
Basically your local network would be on http which is not supported by default due to security reason.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the feedback. Local network already uses https.

Comment: how is that possible? can you explain a little?

Comment: @Rahul now we have a website domain with https but it can only be accessed through the local network. And the local network is not connected or cannot access the internet outside the company's local network such as google.com

Comment: are you able to browse your website within local network from chrome browser?

Comment: @Rahul sample download link: https://xx.com/file.png
The download link if accessed directly through a browser such as Mozilla / Chrome can directly download the file but when using the flutter_downloader plugin no files are downloaded unless there is an internet network that can connect outside the local network such as google.com